# Как выбрать пропущеные ID?

Tags: sql

Есть поле ID в некой таблице Tab, некоторые номера пропущены, например:
1,2,4,5,6,8

Как выбрать номера 3 и 7?

Я давно делал такой запрос и вот не могу вспомнить как )) Там помню в условии было ID+1

Comment: А зачем вам, если не секрет? Не планируете ли вы случайно повторно использовать эти удалённые id?

Answer (score 8):

Алгоритм. Для каждого Id смотрим следующий, если он не равен текущему+1 - находим пропуск.
Пусть есть таблица SomeTable, и у неё записи со значениями id: 5,7,8,11,15
Найдём интервалы пропусков:

```
SELECT id+1 as start_interval, next_id-1 as finish_interval
FROM(
  SELECT id, LEAD(id)OVER(ORDER BY Id)as next_id
  FROM SomeTable
)T
WHERE id+1 <> next_id
```

выдаст:

```
start_interval  finish_interval
6   6
9   10
12  14
```

Если нас интересует интервал от 1 до первого Id, искусственно внедрим в запрос id=0:

```
SELECT id+1 as start_interval, next_id-1 as finish_interval
FROM(
  SELECT id, LEAD(id)OVER(ORDER BY Id)as next_id
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id FROM SomeTable
  )T
)T
WHERE id+1 <> next_id
```

выдаст:

```
start_interval  finish_interval
1   4
6   6
9   10
12  14
```

Примечание: Использовал **MS SQL** начиная с версии 2012, в **Oracle** и **PostgreSQL** вроде тоже должно работать.

Для версий **MS SQL ниже 2012** можно использовать следующий код, который практически не уступает по производительности LEAD():

```
SELECT id1+1 start_interval, id2-1 finish_interval
FROM(
  SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN dN=1 THEN Id END)id1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN dN=0 THEN Id END)id2
  FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id)as N, Id
    FROM SomeTable
  )T1 , ( SELECT 0 as dN UNION ALL SELECT 1 )T2
  GROUP BY N+dN
)T
WHERE Id1+1 <> Id2
```

Для **MySQL** будет выглядеть примерно так

```
SELECT last_id+1 as start_interval, currentId-1 as finish_interval
FROM(
  SELECT @Id last_id, @Id := Id currentId
  FROM SomeTable, (SELECT @Id := NULL)T
  ORDER BY Id
)T
WHERE last_id+1 <> current_id
```

Comment: Для MS SQL дополнительное условие - версия не ниже 2012, до нее LEAD/LAG не было.

Comment: @minamoto, ну это легко поправить :) И до 2012 можно было без самоджойнов. Сейчас в ответ дополню

Answer (score 5):

В общем случае задача решается так - вам нужно получить минимальное значение интервала, максимальное значение, построить таблицу цифр от минимума до максимума и присоединить к ней вашу таблицу, выбрав значения из таблицы цифр, для которых не найдено совпадений в вашей таблице.

Для этого некоторые разработчики заранее готовят таблицу цифр в базе - удобнее ее использовать напрямую, но можно ее создать и на ходу, с использованием CTE, например, если ваш движок поддерживает такую возможность. Я пишу на основе SQL Server, привожу пример, который будет работать на этой СУБД, если для вас не подходит - уточняйте свою СУБД.

```
with numbers as
(
    select min(id) as number
    from    tab
    union all
    select number + 1
    from numbers
    where number < any (select id from tab)
)
select numbers.number
from    tab tab
        right join numbers
                on tab.id = numbers.number
where  tab.id is null
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Всё-таки для такой задачи генерировать последовательность рекурсией плохая идея... Представьте, что есть два Id'а, 1 и 10 000 000. Чтобы узнать интервал пропусков - ваш запрос будет генерить 10 млн. записей. Это не говоря уже о том, что рекурсия работает гораздо медленнее, чем генерация последовательности декартовым произведением.

Comment: Верное замечание, поэтому я и говорил, что многие используют готовую таблицу. Как генерить таблицу цифр - зависит от конкретной ситуации. Рекурсия тут для примера приведена.

Answer (score 4):

postgresql:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM generate_series(1, greatest((SELECT max(id)-1 FROM table), 1) s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = s)
```

`max(id)-1` - зачем нам max(id), если он точно занят?
Написав `max(id)+1`, имеем шанс получить подходящий id для новой записи сразу же. Либо из дырки в нумерации, либо следующий за максимальным. Если конечная задача именно такая.
`generate_series(start, stop)` - генерирует последовательность чисел от `start` до `stop` включительно
`greatest(a, b, ...)` - возвращает наибольшее не null значение из списка. Используется для защиты от генерации пустой последовательности, когда таблица table пустая (stop будет = null) или содержит только одну запись с минимальным id (stop будет = 0)
Предполагается минимальный id = 1

Answer (score 3):

oracle

```
select z.aaa
from (select level aaa from dual connect by level <= (select max(id) from table)) z
left join table x on x.id = z.aaa
where x.id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Мое решение на MySQL, где не поддерживается LEAD:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (6), (8), (9), (12);

SELECT
  id1 AS 'FROM',
  id3 AS 'TO' 
FROM (
SELECT
    t1.id AS id1,
    t2.id AS id2,
    (
      SELECT id FROM test t3 
      WHERE t3.id > t1.id
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS id3 FROM test t1 
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t1.id + 1) A
WHERE id1 IS NOT NULL AND id2 IS NULL AND id3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Для MySQL шустро работает вот это (~1000000 записей):

```
SELECT t1.id + 1 AS empy_id
FROM movie AS t1
LEFT JOIN movie AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id +1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Отображение строк 0 - 49 (78605 всего, Запрос занял 0.0003 сек.)

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tab where ID is not (select ID from tab)
```

Comment: Это пустой запрос, ты пытаешься выбрать того, чего нет. Вот так надо 

    SELECT ID+1 FROM `Tab` WHERE ID+1 NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM `Tab` ) 

на большой таблице зависало, а я подумал, что неправильно запрос написал.

Comment: на больших таблицах будет зависать потому, что NOT IN тяжелая конструкция - перебор сравнивающий всех со всеми... но у меня не может быть пустым запрос,я не вижу смысла в твоем ID+1

Comment: смотря какие данные в таблице, если там просто пустая ячейка, будет лучше запрос - select * from tab where ID is NULL

Comment: Имеется ввиду вообще отсутствие строки с таким ID

Comment: отлично =) тогда что ты хочешь увидеть в запросе?

Comment: Пропущеные ID, выбираются они вот так

SELECT ID+1 FROM Tab WHERE ID+1 NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Tab )

Comment: Вот получше вариант

SELECT t.ID+1 FROM `Tab` t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM `Tab` t2 WHERE t2.ID=t.ID+1)

Comment: Никто не хочет учесть наличие двух дырок подряд?