# SQL команда выборки

Tags: sql

Представим, что есть некая таблица `Users`, в которой есть идентификатор (primary key) с именем `id`. Но по какой-то причине `id` были вырваны строки. И получилась такая вот таблица:

`id 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,12`

Вопрос, как получить с использованием только одного select набор, который включает только остутствующие числа. То есть какой сделать sql запрос ?

Задали вопрос на собеседовании, стало очень интересно.

Comment: уточните, т.е. строка остались, но  "ячейка" id пуста? Если так то что-то вроде select * where id is null or trim(id)=''

Comment: А сравнивать данный набор чисел есть с чем?

Comment: Нет, удалили строки и от этого сбился порядок инкремента. То есть шло все норм, но потом строки вырвали

Comment: @sp7 нет. Я тоже такой вопрос задал ))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выбрать пропущеные ID?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/102635/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-id) причем тот хотя бы по поиску находится. А этот найти будет сложно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это не диапозон (как в вашем случае), то задача решается очень тривиально и просто. Достаточно сделать подзапрос в WHERE, где нет следующего значения:

```
SELECT (`numbers`.`number`+1) AS `not_exists_number`
FROM `numbers`
WHERE
    (SELECT 1
     FROM `numbers` AS `add_table`
     WHERE `add_table`.`number` = (`numbers`.`number` + 1)) IS NULL
ORDER BY `numbers`.`number`;
```

Если действительно нужен один SELECT, то данное решение перепишем на JOIN

```
SELECT l.number + 1 AS missing
FROM numbers AS l
LEFT JOIN numbers AS r ON l.number + 1 = r.number
WHERE r.number IS NULL;
```

Правда тут проблема в двух решениях, что последнее значение будет всегда больше последнего в таблице на 1, но его можно отсечь. Если у Вас было последнее 26, то он еще 27 выведет, но за-то очень просто :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @MaxID INT
DECLARE @MissingID TABLE ( [ID] INT )

SELECT @MaxID = [ID] FROM Users

SET @ID = 1
WHILE @ID <= @MaxID
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users
                   WHERE [ID] = @ID)
        INSERT INTO @MissingID ( [ID] )
        VALUES ( @ID )

    SET @ID = @ID + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @MissingID
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table). Попробовала в MS SQL Server 2008, работает. Правда, по Вашему условию мне не совсем понятно, разрешены ли вложенные select'ы. :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT number
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyTable)
AND number NOT IN (SELECT id FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: Если в таблице `MyTable` больше 2000 (примерно) записей, то работать уже не будет.